# SQL Server student id not in another table

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    'LIFETIME' as SECTION,          
    CPL.StudentID,              
    CPL.MEPeriod        
INTO 
    #NO_STUDENTS
FROM
    #STUDENTS CPL
LEFT JOIN
    #FOR_LIFETIME FL ON CPL.MEPeriod = FL.MEPeriod                  
WHERE
    CPL.StudentID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT FL1.StudentID 
                          FROM #FOR_LIFETIME FL1)
```

I am simply trying to select those Student ID that don't appear in the `#FOR_LIFETIME` table, by month. The `#FOR_LIFETIME` table lists `StudentID` and `MEPeriod`, from '201601' through '201701'

When I run the following the count/records come out fine:

```
SELECT COUNT(loanid)
FROM #STUDENTS
WHERE StudentID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT StudentID
                        FROM #FOR_LIFETIME 
                        WHERE MEperiod = '201612')
  AND MEperiod = '201612'
```

How can I amend my first query to work correctly like the small query does?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using AS instead of = for column aliases - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just correlate the subquery with the outer query on MEPeriod

```
Select 
'LIFETIME' as SECTION,          
CPL.StudentID,              
CPL.MEPeriod        
INTO #NO_STUDENTS
From #STUDENTS CPL
left join #FOR_LIFETIME FL
on CPL.MEPeriod = FL.MEPeriod                   
WHERE
CPL.StudentID not in
(
Select 
  FL1.StudentID  
FROM
#FOR_LIFETIME FL1
WHERE FL1.MEPeriod = CPL.MEPeriod
)
```

or better use - `NOT EXISTS`

```
Select 
'LIFETIME' as SECTION,          
CPL.StudentID,              
CPL.MEPeriod        
INTO #NO_STUDENTS
From #STUDENTS CPL
left join #FOR_LIFETIME FL
on CPL.MEPeriod = FL.MEPeriod                   
WHERE
not exists
(
Select 
  1
FROM
#FOR_LIFETIME FL1
WHERE FL1.MEPeriod = CPL.MEPeriod
AND CPL.StudentID = FL1.StudentID
)
```

Comment: which one is faster/better?

Comment: `not exists()` is faster more often than not. [Should I use `not in`, `outer apply`, `left outer join`, `except`, or `not exists`? - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Comment: Hi.  It is taking forever.. should I add one more line to the join before the WHERE not exists? ...  left join #FOR_LIFETIME FL
on CPL.MEPeriod = FL.MEPeriod   AND CPL.StudentID = FL.StudentID                 
WHERE
not exists
(
Select